# ASF SAMD21G18 2x timers usage

Tags: microcontroller, atmel, atmel-studio, samd21

im trying to use ASF to schedule repeated tasks.

using TC4 and TC5:

in atmel start both using generic clock generator 0 (48MHz).
both are HAL:DRIVER:Timer

driver init.c is generated automatically by atmel start:
[image]

- timer_1_init = TC4
- timer_0_init = TC5

when i comment Timer_1_init() ..

timer0 task runs ok.. 
however, when timer_1_init is called.. the task in tc4 is not called.

i read about tc4 and tc5 have same gclk id so i did this (enable both buses and then enable gclk channel) .. but same issue.. 
[image]

if i comment init of tc4:
- tc5 code works fine
if i comment init of tc5:
- tc4 code works fine
if i dont comment inits:
- tc5 task works (even if i init tc4 before init of tc5)

### ========= edit section =========

```
int32_t timer_init(struct timer_descriptor *const descr, void *const hw, struct _timer_hpl_interface *const func)
{
    ASSERT(descr && hw);
    _timer_init(&descr->device, hw);
    descr->time                           = 0;
    descr->device.timer_cb.period_expired = timer_process_counted;

    return ERR_NONE;
}
```

note device->hw = hw in next func

```
int32_t _timer_init(struct _timer_device *const device, void *const hw)
{
    int8_t i = get_tc_index(hw);

    device->hw = hw;
    ASSERT(ARRAY_SIZE(_tcs));

    hri_tc_wait_for_sync(hw);
    if (hri_tc_get_CTRLA_reg(hw, TC_CTRLA_ENABLE)) {
        hri_tc_write_CTRLA_reg(hw, 0);
        hri_tc_wait_for_sync(hw);
    }
    hri_tc_write_CTRLA_reg(hw, TC_CTRLA_SWRST);
    hri_tc_wait_for_sync(hw);

    hri_tc_write_CTRLA_reg(hw, _tcs[i].ctrl_a);
    hri_tc_write_DBGCTRL_reg(hw, _tcs[i].dbg_ctrl);
    hri_tc_write_EVCTRL_reg(hw, _tcs[i].event_ctrl);

    if ((_tcs[i].ctrl_a & TC_CTRLA_MODE_Msk) == TC_CTRLA_MODE_COUNT32) {
        hri_tccount32_write_CC_reg(hw, 0, _tcs[i].cc0);
        hri_tccount32_write_CC_reg(hw, 1, _tcs[i].cc1);
    } else if ((_tcs[i].ctrl_a & TC_CTRLA_MODE_Msk) == TC_CTRLA_MODE_COUNT16) {
        hri_tccount16_write_CC_reg(hw, 0, (hri_tccount16_cc_reg_t)_tcs[i].cc0);
        hri_tccount16_write_CC_reg(hw, 1, (hri_tccount16_cc_reg_t)_tcs[i].cc1);
    } else if ((_tcs[i].ctrl_a & TC_CTRLA_MODE_Msk) == TC_CTRLA_MODE_COUNT8) {
        hri_tccount8_write_CC_reg(hw, 0, (hri_tccount8_cc_reg_t)_tcs[i].cc0);
        hri_tccount8_write_CC_reg(hw, 1, (hri_tccount8_cc_reg_t)_tcs[i].cc1);
        hri_tccount8_write_PER_reg(hw, _tcs[i].per);
    }
    hri_tc_set_INTEN_OVF_bit(hw);

    _tc_init_irq_param(hw, (void *)device);
    NVIC_DisableIRQ((IRQn_Type)((uint8_t)TC_IRQ_BASE_INDEX + tc_get_hardware_index(hw)));
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ((IRQn_Type)((uint8_t)TC_IRQ_BASE_INDEX + tc_get_hardware_index(hw)));
    NVIC_EnableIRQ((IRQn_Type)((uint8_t)TC_IRQ_BASE_INDEX + tc_get_hardware_index(hw)));

    return ERR_NONE;
}
```

### ==============

what causes this problem?

Comment: these can be tricky sometimes, for example in sam4e micros the clock sources in the datasheet can be somewhat confusing   
in this case how is TIMER_0 and TIMER_1 defined?
also why are you not enabling the clock in TIMER_0_init in contrast to TIMER_1?

Comment: Timer_1 and Timer_0 to my knowledge are actually empty structures. timer_init() will fill them.

Comment: @diegogmx the code is actually doing both init same, what i showed in the post is actually modified version where i dont setup gclk_enable_channel twice. but that didnt work. i set it back to be both same now

Comment: can i see timer_init? never used atmel start, however in asf 2.x i never use empty structs like that, generally the first argument is the pointer to the peripheral, meaning the first config register addr

Comment: @diegogmx i've edited post in edit section and pasted the two functions called. (timer_init and internal _timer_init)

Comment: I see now, those are just descriptors

Comment: reading the datasheet i see the following in the part of the TCs
Features•   Selectable configuration–  Up to five 16-bit Timer/Counters (TC), each configurable as:•   8-bit TC with two compare/capture channels•   16-bit TC with two compare/capture channels•   32-bit TC with two compare/capture channels, by using two TCs   and you are calling TC5, and they start at TC0, meaning that you are actually calling a SIXTH tc, maybe try using TC3 and TC4?

Comment: tc5 works fine when i dont init tc4, i think some how thats confusing they when i see samd21g18.h file the peripheral handlers tcc0,1,2 and tc3,4,5 handler so they mix these TC with TCC in datasheet so its little confusing. but i will try what you suggested and comment back later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is answer from microchip support:

The timer/counter peripheral is actually  a set of 16-bit timers, which can be combined to use as 2 32-bit timers.

When paired, the TC peripherals are configured using the registers of the even-numbered TC (TC4 in this case). The odd-numbered partner (TC5) will act as slave, and the Slave bit in the Status register (STATUS.SLAVE) will be set.

The timer middleware in the Atmel Start configures the timer as 32 bit timers by default, hence it is not possible to use both TC4 and TC5 in two instances of Timer middleware, as both of them will be paired to be used as 32-bit timer and TC5 is acting as slave.

---

to manual change the code generated by atmel start:

```
// Mode set to 32-bit

#ifndef CONF_TC3_MODE
#define CONF_TC3_MODE TC_CTRLA_MODE_COUNT32_Val
#endif
```

in hpl_tc_config.h